# .htaccess include arguments (f. ex. ?keyword=whatever)

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following url pattern:
https://whatever.com/contacts/

I got to make it work with the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

How do I extend it to process the following url pattern:
https://whatever.com/contacts/?anyname=anyvalue&anyname2=anyvalue2&...

I tried it with the following, but any attempts fail:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)=(.*)$ /?page=$1&$2=$3 [L]
```

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKh9S.png)

Comment: You just need to add `QSA` flag in first rule shown here

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, I  did not expect it would be that easy.

Comment: @anubhava If i get it right, QSA appends the arguments from the url to the rewritten url?

Comment: Yes that's right, it is called `Query String Append`